# The Fourier transform of a two variables function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I would like to know how to calculate the the Fourier transform of the function $S:\mathbb{R^2}/\{0\}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ given by

$$S(x_1,x_2)=\frac{(x_2,-x_1)}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$$

in the book I was reading, the author only says that

$$\hat{S}(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)=C\frac{(\zeta_2,-\zeta_1)}{\zeta_1^2+\zeta_2^2}$$
where $C$ is a constant.

And I not used to calculate the transform of a two variables function.

any hint would be really apreciated!

Comment: $(u^2+v^2)f(u,v) = u$ means $-4\pi (\partial_{a^2}+\partial_{b^2}) \widehat{f}(a,b) = \delta_a' / (-2i\pi)$ so to me your text's result isn't correct

Comment: @reuns it's a classical result in the Navier-Stokes theory. I've seen at least two 
 more papers that states this result (in one of then the author says that it's just a direct calculation). So, I think it's correct